# Can't create session client dialogflow

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to set up Dialogflow on a php backend. According to the documentation: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/v2beta1.SessionsClient.html

I should be able to pass as a parameter the path of the json key file I previously generated with the Google Cloud Console to access DialogFlow's API.

```
$path = dirname(__DIR__, 2) . '\_________-_______-____________.json';
$config = [
  'keyFilename' => $path,
];
$sessionsClient = new SessionsClient($config);
```

I keep getting this error: `Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials`

I double checked the path using the `file_get_contents` method, it's valid.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with the doc.

Using the key `credentials` instead of `keyFilename` did the work.

Comment: Maybe because you were referring to the nodejs documentation ;)